# How do I require the user submitted content to be approved before it is published?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I need to have content that is submitted by users of a certain role to be approved by an administrator before it is published. I thought this functionality was build in already, but I just can't seem to find where it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be interested in the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module combined with [Workbench Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation).

From the Workbench project page:

> Workbench provides overall improvements for managing content that
>   Drupal does not provide out of the box. Workbench gives us three
>   important solutions:
>
> - a unified and simplified user interface for users who ONLY have to
>     work with content. This decreases training and support time.
> - the ability to control who has access to edit any content based on an
>     organization's structure not the web site structure
> - a customizable editorial workflow that integrates with the access control feature
>     described above or works independently on its own

From the Workbench Moderation project page:

> Workbench Moderation adds arbitrary moderation states to Drupal core's
>   "unpublished" and "published" node states, and affects the behavior of
>   node revisions when nodes are published. Moderation states are tracked
>   per-revision; rather than moderating nodes, Workbench Moderation
>   moderates revisions.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I'm looking for and more, thanks.

Comment: Excellent looking module. I've not come across it before but will definitely give it a try on my next D7 project.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to setup a workflow.

Comment: I could do that and make the "action" unpublish the content. but what stops the user form republishing the content. Plus I want the user to know that his content will not be published until it's approved.

Comment: Only give roles the "Administer content" permission if you want them to change the publish status and set the default to unpublished. Then make use of rules to control the workflow. You'll probably also want to stop people from editing their own content if they cannot control the publish status.